# libGDX RoboVM fork iOS build error

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx, robovm

I always get the same strange error when I try to run the iOS version of my libGDX game. The error only shows this message: `Error:com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z`

I can sync gradle successfully but the error message stays the same. It was suggested to use the same android studio version as the RoboVM fork version, so I did that. Now I use version 2.3.0 for them both, but it wasn't fixed by doing this. To set up RoboVM I followed the instructions from the RoboVM fork website: http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Answer from Abhishek already stated how to resolve using RoboVM. But building RoboVM manually, I think it's not easy task. Try using MultiOS engine (MOE) instead of RoboVM during this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoboVM having some incompatibly issue with `Android Studio`/`IDEA`, version 2.3.0.

Try to use MobiDevelop `RoboVM 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT` version that having fixes for the same.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/pull/148) for this problem in `master` branch, you can check that.

Comment: Where can I find RoboVM 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT? It's not on here: http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/snapshots/idea/

Comment: @A.Person currently build is not available, you'll have to build it from source.

Comment: either downgrade to old version Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Android studio 2.2.3 was nowhere to be found, so I installed android studio 2.2.0 from: http://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/mac/download/1172101. This combined with RoboVM for 2.2.0 made it work. Thank you very much Abhishek Aryan!

Comment: you can find plugins here http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/snapshots/idea/

Answer (score 0):

You can work-around this problem with Android Studio higher than 2.2 (I am using AS 3.0 Canary 3, which supports Java 8 features) by splitting your project into two separate projects, one for Android and one for iOS, sharing an imported module where all the common code is.

To set this up you will need to copy your iOS app module into a separate folder. I use this structure:

```
Toplevel
    android
        androidApp
        lib
    ios
        iosApp
```

Each project should have a copy of the gradle.build, gradlew script and gradle folders - easiest way is just to duplicate the tree then remove androidApp from one and iosApp from the other.

Both the android and ios folders contain a top level build.gradle, and a settings.gradle file. The common code is in the lib directory, so the ios folder will need a settings.gradle like this

```
include ':iosApp', ':lib'
project(':lib').projectDir = new File('../android/lib')
```

while the android project settings.gradle looks like this:

```
include ':lib', ':androidApp'
```

Open each project in its own window in AS, you can now build and run them independently. You can test from the command line (often easier to debug gradle issues) by using

```
gradlew androidApp:assembleDebug
```

for the android project and

```
gradlew iosApp:assemble
```

for the ios version.
The only issue I currently have with AS 3 is an occasional null pointer error during the dexing phase in the android project. Building from the command line makes this go away for a while. You can of course use AS 2.3 which does not have this issue (but doesn't support Java 8 features like lambdas in Android.)